# IAM Policy for OpsCenter backup to S3 user

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax, opscenter

Using OpsCenter 5.1.0 and trying to add S3 as a location for snapshot backups. What are the necessary permissions in AWS IAM for the opscenter user? So far, I have the following policy:

`"Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cassandra-bkup"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cassandra-bkup/*"
            ]
        }
    ]`

but backups are still failing. In opscenterd.log, the following error is seen:

`WARN: Marking request af93899e-ae89-4ada-8b3b-ef93d0272d61 as failed: {'sstables': {'reporting_test': {u'cards': {'total_size': 9829, 'total_files': 6, 'done_files': 0, 'errors': [u'{:cause :unknown-destination-provider, :message "Specified provider unknown."}', u'{:cause :unknown-destination-provider, :message "Specified provider unknown."}', u'{:cause :unknown-destination-provider, :message "Specified provider unknown."}', u'{:cause :unknown-destination-provider, :message "Specified provider unknown."}', u'{:cause :unknown-destination-provider, :message "Specified provider unknown."}', u'{:cause :unknown-destination-provider, :message "Specified provider unknown."}']},` etc, etc.

Backup to local server succeeds, however.

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error, I found that the following policy worked

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::prod-bkup"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::prod-bkup/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

EDIT: added `s3:GetBucketAcl` as a required permission

Comment: This template worked for me (after replacing the s3 destination name of course)