# OpsCenter S3 backup access denied

Tags: amazon-s3, datastax, datastax-enterprise, amazon-iam, opscenter

I have OpsCenter 5.1.1 and datastax enterprise 4.5.1 3-node cluster. I'm writing backups to S3 - the backups are being written, but I am seeing some errors in the agent.log like so:

`INFO [Thread-1194] 2015-04-23 16:05:23,672 Cleaning up destination 16ed3891f1504461acf54d12567b96a9 for backup 5b940fb2-d7de-40f1-98aa-a81c1620c341 expiration date: 2015-01-23T16:05:23.000Z
 INFO [Thread-1194] 2015-04-23 16:05:23,757 Cleaning up destination 16ed3891f1504461acf54d12567b96a9, removing tags: ()
ERROR [Thread-1194] 2015-04-23 16:05:23,932 #<UncheckedExecutionException com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.jclouds.rest.AuthorizationException: Access Denied>
ERROR [Thread-1194] 2015-04-23 16:05:23,945 com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.jclouds.rest.AuthorizationException: Access Denied`

I posted before about the [IAM policy for the backup-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131437/iam-policy-for-opscenter-backup-to-s3-user) and I think I need to add more rights of some sort or maybe something changed in 5.1.1. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I don't think that the permissions here changed in 5.1.1, what's happening is that there's a configurable cleanup policy in OpsCenter to delete old backups after X period of time.  The error message above is stating that during this cleanup period the user lacks permission to delete old opscenter backups.  I, unfortunately, do not know the IAM policy required here as I use it with very permissive settings in AWS.  However I would be looking to grant permissions around abilities to delete items to try to address this.

Comment: @LHWizard Does this occur when you attempt to initiate a manual backup from OpsCenter to backup locally as well?

Comment: I was able to resolve one error by adding s3:GetBucketAcl to the IAM user. I'll edit my other question to include the added permission

Comment: backup to localhost appears to be working, it's the remote location backup to S3 that is failing.