# Cassandra DSE, restore from S3 timeouts

Tags: amazon-s3, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'm trying to test S3 backup/restore functionality.
What I did:

1. installed DSE +OpsCenter on Amazon
2. Scheduled hourly backup of all keyspaces (60 MB total size). got 10 backups in the morning.
3. Terminate instances and create new one
4. try to get my data back. No luck. OpsCenter can't connect to my S3 bucket
   [image]

it takes >10 min now...

What do I do wrong?

UPD:

finally, got response:
[image]

Comment: Looks like OpsCenter problem. When I try to restore backup from empty basket, it reports immediately that there are no backups...

Comment: does your IAM policy grant enough rights to the opscenter user? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131437/iam-policy-for-opscenter-backup-to-s3-user) is the policy I'm using but I haven't tried a restore yet.

Comment: Yes, I used that policy to backup and fail to restore. I've enabled debug in OpsCenter. OpsCenter gets response from S3 in 5-7 minutes (see it in opscenterd.log), but OpsCenter UI throw error earlier and don't take care of late response.

Comment: also check for S3 errors in the agent.log - I'm currently trying to debug this error `SEVERE: error after writing 15540224/16777216 bytes to https://cass-bkup.s3.amazonaws.com/`

Comment: did it, no error during writing, I see all my backups in S3. Just OpsCenter can't wait until it's layout/metadata fetched.

Comment: It’d be great to get full agent log from one of the machines, ideally on DEBUG level

Comment: I would ask guys to publish it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this may be OPSC-5915 (sorry no public bug tracker) which is fixed in the upcoming 5.2.0 release.

The summary is that the API calls will still work as expected but the UI is not pushing the destination information to the API endpoint correctly.

You can confirm that this is the error you are experiencing thusly:

```
1) goto /etc/opscenter/clusters/<cluster_name>.conf (or similar location depending on if you've done a tarball install/etc)
2) Find the destination ID that matches your bucket, it'll look something like b699738d9bd8409c82e664b543f24030
3) Confirm the clustername in your opsc URLs, it'll look something like localhost:8888/my_cluster
4) Manually hit the API to retrieve your backup list
curl localhost:8888/<clustername>/backups?amount=6\&last_seen=\&list_all=1\&destination=<destination ID>
It'll look like this
curl localhost:8888/dse/backups?amount=6\&last_seen=\&list_all=1\&destination=b699738d9bd8409c82e664b543f24030
5) You should get back a json, confirm that your backup is listed
{"opscenter_adhoc_2014-12-17-20-22-57-UTC": {"keyspaces": {"OpsCenter":...
```

If you see your backup in the JSON, then opsc sees your backup and this is indeed OPSC-5915, so that's at least confirmed.

If this is your case, we can work around it by manually hitting the restore API (this is admittedly a bit more involved).

http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/api/docs/backups.html#backups

It'll look a bit like this:

```
  BACKUP='opscenter_4a269167-96c1-40c7-84b7-b070c6bcd0cd_2012-06-07-18-00-00-UTC'
    curl -X POST
        http://192.168.1.1:8888/Test_Cluster/backups/restore/$BACKUP
        -d '{
          "destination": "fe85800f3f4043a88fbe76fc45b22b19",
          "keyspaces": {
            "Keyspace1": {
              "column-families: ["users", "dates"],
              "truncate": true
            },
            "OpsCenter": {
              "truncate": false
            }
          },
        }'
```

Comment: Thanks, we decided to do the same, jus fall back to API.